# Android Studio 3.0 stuck in refreshing project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.0

After updating Android Studio 3.0 stable version from 2.3.3 my previous project is refreshing forever. I deleted app folder build file but it's not working.

Comment: Post your error or screenshot

Comment: show your `log`.

Comment: it's not error. refreshing progress bar running forever.

Comment: i just upgrade it. project refresh completed. Try to delete .gradle folder from User folder

Comment: I deleted still not working.

Comment: Same here. Keep refreshing for last 30min

Comment: why they are giving down voting.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar issue. This what helped me to recover.

- Close your Android Studio.
- Remove the build, .gradle and .iml files (or use `gradle clean`)
- Open your project path in command prompt. Execute `gradlew build`.
- Once the build is success from cmd, open it in Studio.

If you are using gradle instead of gradle wrapper, use `gradle build'

Answer (score 1):

"Refreshing project" generally means the new version of gradle is being downloaded. About 100MB of file will be downloaded during the process. Make sure you have a stable internet connection and wait for a while.